# Server 2012 R2 - Unable to print randomly

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, printing, rds

From the time our servers were built we have had on and off printing issues with them.

The current issue is affecting random users and will only prevent them from printing from within certain programs.

Basically, user 1 will be able to print but users 2 will only be able to print from word and excel. They are both using the same printer, and they are able to fix this issue by removing and re-adding the printer (Sometimes this does require a spooler restart).

No errors show up in the event log.

The print job doesn't even queue, it just disappears.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this would happen or how I would troubleshoot the cause?

Comment: you could look in the logs :-/

Comment: Mapped printer ?

Comment: Have you tried printing deliberately?  I mean, if printing randomly isn't working, perhaps printing in an organized, deliberate fashion will yield different results.

Comment: @Sum1sAdmin  As noted in the original post, no errors in log.

Comment: @yagmoth555 Yes these are mapped with a central print server.

Comment: @HopelessN00b I have attempted this previously but again no replication, some users wont have any issues for days then suddenly it stops.

Comment: If mapped, then try to remove on the printserver the SNMP state in the port if it's TCP/IP printqueue. It happened to me a bug like your in the past, that option solved the issue. That option send a lot of query, and on a big printserver with other roles problem arised for me.